# How can I test email confirmation on my local computer?

Tags: email, visual-studio-2015, identity

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Web forms and going through the Identity API for the first time. I see there is an entire section for a user who is registering to receive the confirmation email where they would click and then login and change their password. All good. But I don't have a server to send emails quite yet. I'd like to test this locally. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can install a local smtp server.  There's quite a few of them available (xmailserver, hMailServer, papercut).  You could also use a 3rd part smtp server (gmail, godaddy, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an application called [smtp4dev](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/). This intercepts any smtp requests sent to your local machine and you can view/save the emails generated.